# Getting part of a JSON using Regex

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I have a json response but I have some problems with using Gson or Klaxon because I only need one(or more if found) strings to put in an array. So i have an JSON, for example:

```
"AddressLine":"Adress 1",
"AddressLine":"Adress 2",
...
"AddressLine":"Adress N",
```

I have a function for this:

```
private fun getArrayFromJson(response: String): Array<String> {
    val pattern = ".AddressLine.:\".*?\""
    val regex = Regex(pattern)
    val matchedResults = regex.findAll(response, 0)
    val result = mutableListOf<String>()
    matchedResults.forEach { p0 ->
        result.add(p0.value)
    }
    return result.toTypedArray()
}
```

The main problem is that i only need "AddressLine" value without quotes.

But I don't mind if you help me to do this using Klaxon or Gson.

Full json response, if needed:

```
{
"response": {
"GeoObjectCollection": {
  "metaDataProperty": {
    "GeocoderResponseMetaData": {
      "Point": {
        "pos": "45.042529 38.975963"
      },
      "request": "45.042529,38.975963",
      "results": "10",
      "found": "2"
    }
  },
  "featureMember": [
    {
      "GeoObject": {
        "metaDataProperty": {
          "GeocoderMetaData": {
            "precision": "other",
            "text": "Иран, Западный Азербайджан",
            "kind": "province",
            "Address": {
              "country_code": "IR",
              "formatted": "Иран, Западный Азербайджан",
              "Components": [
                {
                  "kind": "country",
                  "name": "Иран"
                },
                {
                  "kind": "province",
                  "name": "Западный Азербайджан"
                }
              ]
            },
            "AddressDetails": {
              "Country": {
                "AddressLine": "Иран, Западный Азербайджан",
                "CountryNameCode": "IR",
                "CountryName": "Иран",
                "AdministrativeArea": {
                  "AdministrativeAreaName": "Западный Азербайджан"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "name": "Западный Азербайджан",
        "description": "Иран",
        "boundedBy": {
          "Envelope": {
            "lowerCorner": "44.032702 35.973002",
            "upperCorner": "47.392087 39.782107"
          }
        },
        "Point": {
          "pos": "44.868153 37.716911"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "GeoObject": {
        "metaDataProperty": {
          "GeocoderMetaData": {
            "precision": "other",
            "text": "Иран",
            "kind": "country",
            "Address": {
              "country_code": "IR",
              "formatted": "Иран",
              "Components": [
                {
                  "kind": "country",
                  "name": "Иран"
                }
              ]
            },
            "AddressDetails": {
              "Country": {
                "AddressLine": "Иран",
                "CountryNameCode": "IR",
                "CountryName": "Иран"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "name": "Иран",
        "boundedBy": {
          "Envelope": {
            "lowerCorner": "44.032702 24.872455",
            "upperCorner": "63.317241 39.782107"
          }
        },
        "Point": {
          "pos": "54.221233 33.733982"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
 }
}
```

I was using Gson to parse an array from json:

```
private fun getArrayFromJson() {
val jsonteststring = jsonResponse
val addressArrayType = object : TypeToken<Point>(){}.type
val addressVariants: Array<Point> = Gson().fromJson(jsonteststring, addressArrayType)
```

Point class:

```
data class Point(val AddressLine: String){
override fun toString(): String {
    return AddressLine
    }
}
```

But all I got was an exeption:

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mainproject/com.example.mainproject.PointProperties}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mainproject.Point cannot be cast to com.example.mainproject.Point[]

If i'm using smaller json string which I have found on internet:

```
"""[{"title":"Kotlin Tutorial #1","author":"bezkoder","categories":["Kotlin, Basic"]},
        {"title":"Kotlin Tutorial #2","author":"bezkoder","categories":["Kotlin, Practice"]}]"""
```

It works fine when I change `TypeToken<Point>` to `TypeToken<Array<Point>>` and rename `AddressLine` in `Point` to `title` so I guess that my big json is not so easy to parse

Comment: `I have some problems with using Gson or Klaxon` what problems? Instead of using a Regex I think you should fix those problems and try to use what is standard for JSON parsing.

Comment: @cutiko added this to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have with Gson is that you are trying to cast the whole JSON to a part of the JSON. You have to either have a full class reflecting the complete JSON or traverse the JSON until you get where you need.

```
fun getAddressLines() : List<String> {
    val jsonObject = Gson().fromJson(RESPONSE, JsonObject::class.java)
    val response = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("response")
    val geoObjectCollection = response.getAsJsonObject("GeoObjectCollection")
    val featureMember = geoObjectCollection.getAsJsonArray("featureMember")
    return featureMember.map { jsonElement ->
        val memberChild = jsonElement.asJsonObject
        val geoObject = memberChild.getAsJsonObject("GeoObject")
        val metaData = geoObject.getAsJsonObject("metaDataProperty")
        val geocoder = metaData.getAsJsonObject("GeocoderMetaData")
        val addressDetails = geocoder.getAsJsonObject("AddressDetails")
        val country = addressDetails.getAsJsonObject("Country")
        country.get("AddressLine").asString
    }
}
```

That will enter into each JSON object and iterate the array to return all of the address lines.